# How to implement the rubber band effect?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I found this code online that implements the rubber band effect when panning a view:

```
@IBAction func viewDragged(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

  let yTranslation = sender.translationInView(view).y
    if (hasExceededVerticalLimit(topViewConstraint.constant)){
      totalTranslation += yTranslation
      topViewConstraint.constant = logConstraintValueForYPoisition(totalTranslation)
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended ){
       animateViewBackToLimit()
    }
    } else {
      topViewConstraint.constant += yTranslation
    }
     sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
 }

 func logConstraintValueForYPoisition(yPosition : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
  return verticalLimit * (1 + log10(yPosition/verticalLimit))
 }
```

The resulting effect is shown in the gif below:

[image]

However, I have trouble understanding how this code works, and reproducing this effect in my own projects. For instance, one of the things I do not understand is, when panning the green view upwards `yTransition` is going to be negative and negative numbers do not have logarithms (in the `logConstraintValueForYPoisition(:)` method). I would really appreciate it if someone could explain to me how this code works step by step.

[The original post can be found here.](https://medium.com/thoughts-on-thoughts/recreating-apple-s-rubber-band-effect-in-swift-dbf981b40f35#.h21uyg1f9)

Comment: You can use `UIView.animate(:usingSpringWithDamping)` to have spring animate also

Comment: @Tj3n: They do use that. The log is for something else.

Comment: guess the log is using for maximum over position that the spring animation have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `log` is not what you're thinking of. In fact, the snippet is incomplete. The repo can be found [here](https://github.com/Produkt/RubberBandEffect).

The bouncing animation is [here](https://github.com/Produkt/RubberBandEffect/blob/fa1777a70380a97bf680015359c7d09377d20360/FrictionCurves/SecondViewController.swift):

```
func animateViewBackToLimit() {
    self.topViewConstraint.constant = self.verticalLimit

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.totalTranslation = -200
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

The `log` portion is for moving the green rectangle up. Once you reach an upward threshold (`hasExceededVerticalLimit(topViewConstraint.constant)`) you want the rectangle to stop moving as quick as you don't want it to keep up with your finger, you do this by calling `logConstraintValueForYPoisition`.

Note that if you have a positive value `x`, `log(x) < x`.