# How to create the rubberband effect?

Tags: ios, swift

**What is a full example of how to implement the rubber banding effect?** **How can I implement this?**

[I have tried the following: However, I have been unsuccessful in finding how to implement this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406064/how-to-implement-the-rubber-band-effect)

Currently I have created a card view which can be pulled up to a certain point, however currently when you reach the max there is a sudden halt, which I would like to change to a rubber band effect.

Here is the code I have been using to try and add this:

```
enum SheetLevel{
    case top, bottom, middle
}

protocol BottomSheetDelegate {
    func updateBottomSheet(frame: CGRect)
}

class BottomSheetViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var panView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UICollectionView!
    //    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! //header view

    var lastY: CGFloat = 0
    var pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    var bottomSheetDelegate: BottomSheetDelegate?
    var parentView: UIView!

    var initalFrame: CGRect!
    var topY: CGFloat = 80 //change this in viewWillAppear for top position
    var middleY: CGFloat = 400 //change this in viewWillAppear to decide if animate to top or bottom
    var bottomY: CGFloat = 600 //no need to change this
    let bottomOffset: CGFloat = 64 //sheet height on bottom position
    var lastLevel: SheetLevel = .middle //choose inital position of the sheet

    var disableTableScroll = false

    //hack panOffset To prevent jump when goes from top to down
    var panOffset: CGFloat = 0
    var applyPanOffset = false

    //tableview variables
    var listItems: [Any] = []
    var headerItems: [Any] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
        pan.delegate = self
        self.panView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

        self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))

        //Bug fix #5. see https://github.com/OfTheWolf/UBottomSheet/issues/5
        //Tableview didselect works on second try sometimes so i use here a tap gesture recognizer instead of didselect method and find the table row tapped in the handleTap(_:) method
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        //Bug fix #5 end
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.initalFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.topY = round(initalFrame.height * 0.5)
        self.middleY = initalFrame.height * 0.6
        self.bottomY = initalFrame.height - bottomOffset
        self.lastY = self.middleY

        bottomSheetDelegate?.updateBottomSheet(frame: self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.middleY))
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        guard scrollView == tableView else {return}

        if (self.parentView.frame.minY > topY){
            self.tableView.contentOffset.y = 0
        }
    }


    //this stops unintended tableview scrolling while animating to top
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        guard scrollView == tableView else {return}

        if disableTableScroll{
            targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
            disableTableScroll = false
        }
    }

    //Bug fix #5. see https://github.com/OfTheWolf/UBottomSheet/issues/5
    @objc func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let p = recognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
        //Commented below to prevenet error.. *** apr 2 guillermo
        //        let index = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: p)
        //        //WARNING: calling selectRow doesn't trigger tableView didselect delegate. So handle selected row here.
        //        //You can remove this line if you dont want to force select the cell
        //        tableView.selectRow(at: index, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }//Bug fix #5 end


    @objc func handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
//        var x = topY
//        var c = 0.55
//        var d = view.frame.height
//        var formula = (1.0 - (1.0 / ((x * c / d) + 1.0))) * d

        let dy = recognizer.translation(in: self.parentView).y
        print(recognizer.translation(in: self.parentView).y, " This si dy")
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            applyPanOffset = (self.tableView.contentOffset.y > 0)
        case .changed:
            print(".changed here")
            if self.tableView.contentOffset.y > 0{
                panOffset = dy
                return
            }

            if self.tableView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
                if !applyPanOffset{panOffset = 0}
                let maxY = max(topY, lastY + dy - panOffset)
                let y = min(bottomY, maxY)
                print(y, ".inside if let thindfahfvdsgjafjsda8", maxY)
                //                self.panView.frame = self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: y)
                bottomSheetDelegate?.updateBottomSheet(frame: self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: y))
            }

            if self.parentView.frame.minY > topY{
                print(self.tableView.contentOffset.y, " Thsi is taht y vakue thing")
                self.tableView.contentOffset.y = 0
            }
        case .failed, .ended, .cancelled:
            panOffset = 0
            print(".failed and enededh rhere")

            //bug fix #6. see https://github.com/OfTheWolf/UBottomSheet/issues/6
            if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y > 0){
                return
            }//bug fix #6 end

            self.panView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

            self.disableTableScroll = self.lastLevel != .top

            self.lastY = self.parentView.frame.minY
            self.lastLevel = self.nextLevel(recognizer: recognizer)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                print("Animation!!!!!")
                switch self.lastLevel {
                case .top:
                    print("in this thanaagaggagagagagagagalanfg")
                    //                    self.panView.frame = self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.topY)
//                    self.bottomSheetDelegate?.updateBottomSheet(frame: self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.topY))
//                    self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = 50
                    self.bottomSheetDelegate?.updateBottomSheet(frame: self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.middleY))

                case .middle:
                    //                    self.panView.frame = self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.middleY)
                    self.bottomSheetDelegate?.updateBottomSheet(frame: self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.middleY))
                case .bottom:
                    //                    self.panView.frame = self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.bottomY)
                    self.bottomSheetDelegate?.updateBottomSheet(frame: self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.bottomY))
                }

            }) { (_) in
                print("Someghtifgnshdfgbk")
                self.panView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.lastY = self.parentView.frame.minY
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func nextLevel(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> SheetLevel{
        let y = self.lastY
        let velY = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view).y
        if velY < -200{
            return y > middleY ? .middle : .top
        }else if velY > 200{
            return y < (middleY + 1) ? .middle : .bottom
        }else{
            if y > middleY {
                return (y - middleY) < (bottomY - y) ? .middle : .bottom
            }else{
                return (y - topY) < (middleY - y) ? .top : .middle
            }
        }
    }
}

extension BottomSheetViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SimpleTableCell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleTableCell
        let model = SimpleTableCellViewModel(image: nil, title: "Title \(indexPath.row)", subtitle: "Subtitle \(indexPath.row)")
        cell.configure(model: model)
        return cell
    }
}

extension BottomSheetViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: you're looking for PullUpController. [Link](https://github.com/MarioIannotta/PullUpController)

Comment: Take help from [here](https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/TDStickyController) too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is exponentially decrease the length that user is adding by dragging. There are different formula for this such as using sqrt, log10, and etc.

Here's what I've done:

### [image: Heading]

And here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy private var box : UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300))
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    private var panGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    private var boxOriginY : CGFloat = 300.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(box)

        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pullUp(with:)))
        box.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    @objc private func pullUp(with pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let yTranslation = pan.translation(in: self.view).y

        if pan.state == .changed {
            let distance = CGFloat(sqrt( Double(-yTranslation) ) * 10) // times 10 to make it smoother
            let newHeight : CGFloat = boxOriginY + distance

            box.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                               y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-(newHeight),
                               width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                               height: newHeight)
        }

        if pan.state == .ended {
            if pan.state == UIPanGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.box.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300)

                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No I am looking for some sort of thing where I set a max and then when the user trys to drag beyond that point the draging slows down (as you move) so that it quickly makes it almost unmovable. (ie. The more u move there is almost no notacible change )

Comment: Edited my answer.