# Rubberband effect for scrolling containers

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to have a rubberband effect on scrolling containers for which I feel the  "tensile scrolling" that is build into the Component base class is no sufficient replacement.

Is there a reasonably feasible way like disabling the default overscroll behavior in order to control the property scrollY in a way like in this example - [How to create the rubberband effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507618/how-to-create-the-rubberband-effect)

Comment: What problems do you see in the "tensile dragging" of Codename One? IMHO the "tensile dragging" and the "rubber band scrolling" seems identical... However, you can disable the tensile dragging using the theme constant `tensileDragBool`. To set the Y scroll position, there is a related discussion here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2826

Comment: No, the Codename One tensile scrolling has no rubberband effect at all. Look at a native app or at this - https://www.cultofmac.com/489256/bas-ording-rubber-band-effect-iphone/

Comment: Tensile is our term for the rubber band effect

Comment: Well, it‘s not anything like the real thing

Comment: Flutter did a good job at it. If anything it’s probably even better than the native IOS rubberband effect

Comment: You are right. I've been experimenting with container code for months to see how to implement this effect in CN1. It's more difficult than I thought but I think it's doable. My use case for this is to have an image or video zooming in until the final breakpoint of the rubber band effect is reached and have the media stop zooming or snap-bounce back to original position. SwipeableContainer is also a painful API to use because of this effect not available in CN1 and pullToRefresh is too buggy on real device when rotated due to this. Hopefully I or anyone else finds a way to introduce this soon.

Comment: To answer the question "What problems do you see in the "tensile dragging" of Codename One?" - see this issue - [RFE: Rubberband effect for tensile scrolling](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2846)

Answer (score 2):

Since there was no answer to my question I answer it myself. Beware that I am not an expert and therefore this might not fit Your purpose!

The default overscroll behaviour can be overridden by extending the `Container` class and overriding the pointer methods without calling their super methods.

Here is an example:

```
import com.codename1.ui.Component;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.animations.Motion;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Point;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;

public class FormOverscroll extends Form {
    FormOverscroll() {
        super("FormOverscroll");
        setScrollable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Container container = new Container(BoxLayout.y()) {
            boolean bounce = false;
            Motion motion = null;
            Point pointPressed = null;
            long millisPoint = 0;
            int scrollYPressed = 0, scrollYPrevious = 0;
            {
//              setTensileDragEnabled(false);
                setScrollableY(true);
            }
            @Override
            protected boolean isStickyDrag() {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {
                pointPressed = new Point(x, y);
                scrollYPressed = scrollYPrevious = getScrollY();
                millisPoint = System.currentTimeMillis();
                motion = null;
                bounce = false;
            }
            @Override
            public void pointerDragged(int x, int y) {
                if (null == pointPressed) {
                    return;
                }
                int yDist = y - pointPressed.getY();
                int scrollY = scrollYPressed - yDist;
                if (scrollY < 0) {
                    Motion motionRubberband = Motion.createCubicBezierMotion(0, scrollY, getHeight(), 0f, 1.2f, 0.5f, 0.6f);
                    motionRubberband.setStartTime(0);
                    motionRubberband.setCurrentMotionTime(Math.abs(scrollY));
                    scrollY = motionRubberband.getValue();
                }
                setScrollY(scrollY);
            }
            float getVelocity(int scrollY) {
                long millisNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long timediff = millisNow - millisPoint;
                float diff = scrollYPrevious - scrollY;
                float velocity = (diff / timediff) * -1f;
                scrollYPrevious = scrollY;
                millisPoint = millisNow;
                return velocity;
            }
            @Override
            public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
                if (null == pointPressed) {
                    return;
                }
                int yDist = y - pointPressed.getY();
                int scrollY = scrollYPressed - yDist;
                float velocity = getVelocity(scrollY);
                motion = Motion.createFrictionMotion(scrollY, Integer.MIN_VALUE, velocity,  0.0007f);
                motion.start();
                getComponentForm().registerAnimated(this);
                pointPressed = null;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean animate() {
                boolean animate = super.animate();
                if (null != motion) {
                    int scrollY = motion.getValue();
                    setScrollY(scrollY);
                    int target = 0;
                    if (scrollY < target && !bounce) {
                        createRubberbandMotion(scrollY, target);
                        bounce = true;
                        motion.start();
                    }
                    int maxScrollY = Math.max(target, getScrollDimension().getHeight() - getHeight());
                    if (scrollY > maxScrollY && !bounce) {
                        createRubberbandMotion(scrollY, maxScrollY);
                        bounce = true;
                        motion.start();
                    }
                    scrollYPrevious = scrollY;
                    if (motion.isFinished()) {
                        motion = null;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return animate;
            }
            private void createRubberbandMotion(int source, int target) {
                motion = Motion.createCubicBezierMotion(source, target, 500, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.2f, 1.0f);
            }
            @Override
            public Component getComponentAt(int x, int y) {
                return this;
            }
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) {
                super.paint(aGraphics);

            }
        };
        for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
            container.add(new Label("Zeile " + index));
        }
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, container);
    }

}
```